# ASP.Net checkbox postback doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, postback

I'm making a change to an existing ASP.Net application via JS.  I'm unable to look at nor edit the original ASP.Net code.  What I am able to do is inject JS into the webpage.  There are two radio buttons, and I want to change the default from one to the other, which I can do easily via JS.  But when using the web app, when the other radio is chosen I can easily see there is a server post back happening and my JS code to toggle the checkbox does not fire this.  Because of this, some server side function isn't getting ran to allow me to submit the form.

Just for reference here is my JS code that works fine, nothing to troubleshoot here.  But even after inspecting the radio in Chrome I'm unable to see any event being fired.  I might not fully understand how to inspect elements in chrome, any advice?

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // this tests for the selected value
    if ($("input[name*='radShippingAddressList']:checked").val() == "radSelectAddress") {

     // this changes the radio button
         $("input[name*='radShippingAddressList'][value='radAsBilling']").prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to invoke the click method on the checkbox, in order for post-back to happen and the server side code to run.  Try doing this instead of setting checked to true:
$("input[name*='radShippingAddressList'][value='radAsBilling']").click();

Comment: @HaukurHaf thanks that worked and caused the default postback to happen.  Please repost this as an answer to my question so I can mark it answered and get you the rep.

Comment: Done.  Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke the click method on the checkbox, in order for post-back to happen and the server side code to run. Try doing this instead of setting checked to true:

$("input[name*='radShippingAddressList'][value='radAsBilling']").click();

Answer (score 0):

Auto postback on the control has to be enabled in order for prop changes to affect post back.

```
AutoPostBack="True"
```